# Controlling azure WebJob function calls

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have an Azure continuous web job that has a couple of methods. The first method *CleanupDb* is a [Singleton] and is triggered every 5 minutes, the second multi-threaded method *ProcessXML* is triggered using a queue. ProcessXml peforms bulk copy of data to a database from xml stored in blob storage, but when the CleanupDb method runs I would like to:

1. Suspend the queue trigger for *ProcessXml* for the duration of CleanupDb
2. Wait for any current instances of *ProcessXml* to complete
3. Perform update on the database
4. Re-enable calls to *ProcessXml* when the database cleanup is completed.

How can I achieve this? Do I need to use Semaphores or Mutex for inter-thread communication? Is it possible to disable the QueueTrigger? Finally should I be using TabLock on the bulk copy operation - the target table has a clustered index but I haven't noticed issues?

```
    [Singleton]
    public async static Task CleanupDb([TimerTrigger("0 0/5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = false)]TimerInfo info, TextWriter log)
    {

        // disable any calls to ProcessXML based on import-request queue
        // Wait for any current calls to ProcessXML to complete

        using (XmlNetworkModel ctxt = new XmlNetworkModel())
        {
            ctxt.Database.CommandTimeout = 0;
            await ctxt.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("exec stpCleanupDb");

        }

        // re-enable calls to ProcessXML


    }


    // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
    // on an Azure Queue called queue.
    public async static Task ProcessXML(
        [QueueTrigger("import-request")] BlobInformation blobInfo,
        [Blob("import/{BlobName}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream blobInStream,
        [Blob("import/{BlobName}")] CloudBlockBlob blobIn, TextWriter log)
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["model"].ConnectionString, 
                        SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock)) // should TableLock be used with parallel threads here?
        {

            await sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync([mydatafromblobInStream]);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to temporarily disable the queue trigger once it is running. I'll also mention that TimerTrigger is already Singleton implicitly by default. It takes a Singleton lock behind the scenes, to ensure only one instance of your scheduled function is running across scaled out instances. So your additional Singleton attribute is likely not needed.

One option would be to use singleton on **both** functions, using the same lock scope (e.g. `[Singleton("xmlimport")]`). That would ensure that the functions won't run concurrently - they both require the same lock. For example, while `CleanupDB` is running, any `ProcessXML` invocations will wait for the lock, and vice-versa. One potential drawback to this is that **your queue function will now also be serialized** - only a single queue message will be processed at a time, even if your clean function is not running. If you expect high throughput on the queue, you probably don't want that. But if import operations don't happen very often, it might be an option for you.

Using in process synchronization wouldn't work if you've scaled out your WebJob to multiple instances, you'd again need some sort of distributed locking like Singleton provides.

Another option would be to ensure that your DB cleanup sproc can run concurrently so you don't have to worry about synchronization. Not sure if that is an option for you. For example, ensuring that the cleanup operation only operates on old data, so in progress imports don't interfere, etc.

Comment: So it turns out that you can't actually currently use Singleton across function instances like I indicated above. By default, the blob path used for the lock always includes the fully qualified function name. I've created an [issue here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/618) in our public repo to enable this scenario.

Comment: Thanks - its looking like the best option might be to ensure cleanupdb only operates on 'old' data. To do this effieciently I might require some kind of 'rolling' partition scheme - I have been looking into this. It could be y cleanup db isnt currently working because BulkCopy is placing a TabLock - I will try to remove it.

Comment: Looking at github - I think I am correct that the issue with Singleton scope is now fixed with azure web job sdk 1.1.1 https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/618

Comment: Yes support for this was added in 1.1.1. You can read more in the wiki [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton#locking-across-different-functions).

Comment: Thanks mathewc. What happens when I use the same singleton lock on two or more timer functions? If one locks the other will the locked out process retry on failure? For example if I have a timer firing every 5 minutes and another once a day if the 5 minute timer process happens to overrun and 'lock out' the daily one will the daily retry without waiting 24hrs?

Comment: TimerTrigger uses an implicit Singleton behind the scenes to ensure that only a single instance of each of your timer functions is running across scaled out instances. See the [wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger) page for more details. Each function has its own independent schedule/lock.